# Borrowing reference and guard together from a Mutex

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to encapsulate some code to avoid repeating it, relating to borrowing data out of a Mutex and further operations thereupon (which I leave off of this question as out of scope, but are the motivating factors).

The following sample code complains that `guard` does not live long enough.  But that is precisely why I'm returning `guard` in the structure designed expressly for that purpose.

Is this a limitation of the borrow checker?  Any suggestions on working around this?

```
use std::sync::{Mutex,MutexGuard};
use std::ops::DerefMut;

pub struct InnerData {
    count: i32  // sample only
}

pub struct Data {
    pub inner_data: Mutex<InnerData>
}

pub struct BorrowedInnerData<'a> {
    pub inner_data: &'a mut InnerData,
    guard: MutexGuard<'a,InnerData>,
}

impl Data {
    pub fn borrow_inner_data<'a>(&'a mut self) -> BorrowedInnerData<'a> {
        let guard = self.inner_data.lock().unwrap();
        BorrowedInnerData {
            inner_data: guard.deref_mut(),
            guard: guard,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data {
        inner_data: Mutex::new( InnerData {
            count: 5
        }),
    };

    let borrowed_inner_data = data.borrow_inner_data();
}
```

Comment: Consider what happens to an internal pointer when a struct is moved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the [`DerefMut` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html#tymethod.deref_mut):

```
pub trait DerefMut: Deref {
    fn deref_mut(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut Self::Target;
}
```

This means that when `deref_mut` is called, a reference is returned that *lives as long as the value being dereferenced*. However, you are moving `guard` when you move it to `BorrowedInnerData`. This means that the value stops living at one memory location and starts at a new one. As [Veedrac hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194269/borrowing-reference-and-guard-together-from-a-mutex#comment52273919_32194269), it's entirely possible that by moving the guard, you would invalidate the reference. This would be bad and lead to crashes (in the best case).

However, there's no real reason to keep `guard` and `inner_data`. Because of `Deref` and `DerefMut`, a `MutexGuard<InnerData>` can be used just like a `&InnerData` or `&mut InnerData`. Simply remove `inner_data` from your struct and keep `guard`.

Comment: Thanks, that clear up the mystery.  :-)  Unfortunately in my actual use case, I'm still stuck with repeating a lot of code.  See http://pastebin.com/2Vy5RYmG and the block of code in run_thread() for my motivation here.  I'm trying to not repeat myself so much every time I need to access the current thread's session.

Comment: @AntManelope I guess I'm missing the problem. After [a little refactoring](http://is.gd/kWTb2s), there's not all that much duplication, in my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm off and running now.