# How to store rusqlite Connection and Statement objects in the same struct in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm working on my first Rust program and have run afoul of Rust ownership semantics.  I have declared a `struct` which will encapsulate a SQLite database connection so it maintains a `Connection` member.  For performance reasons, I also want to keep a prepared statement, represented by the `Statement` type.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
extern crate rusqlite; // 0.14.0

use rusqlite::{Connection, Statement};

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    conn: Connection,
    statement: Statement<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Foo<'a> {
        let conn = Connection::open(&":memory:").unwrap();
        let statement = conn
            .prepare("INSERT INTO Foo(name, hash) VALUES($1, $2)")
            .unwrap();
        Foo { conn, statement }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to transfer ownership of the `conn` variable to the callee by storing it in a member of `Foo`, but when I attempt to compile this code it fails:

```
error[E0597]: `conn` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:25
   |
13 |         let statement = conn
   |                         ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 10:6...
  --> src/main.rs:10:6
   |
10 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      ^^
```

For some reason, the `rusqlite::Connection` type doesn't take a lifetime parameter, so I'm unable to explicitly tie its lifetime to that of the `Statement` instance.

What am I missing?  This kind of encapsulation is a very common pattern, I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: This is the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/20698384/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/30538387/155423 or really any of the numerous questions that ask the question "how do I have a reference to 'foo' and then move 'foo'?". There was [this question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32194269/155423) as well. The short version is that once you have a reference into an item, you can't move that item because it would invalidate the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the nomenclature, but in my example I don't think I'm using references.  I intend to transfer ownership of the `SqliteConnection` from the scope of the `new` function to the `Foo` struct, which itself is to be owned by the caller of the `new` function.

Comment: I'd recommend changing your title to something more specific, like "How do I have a `SqliteStatement` and `SqliteConnection` in the same struct". As it is now, your title isn't focused enough as transferring ownership to a struct is easy, but isn't what your problem is.

Comment: If we define the best answer as the one that clarified for me exactly why what I was trying to do is not possible by design, then your answer to this question is definitely the best.  I had seen that other question but I did not grasp the way in which what I was attempting was in effect the same thing.

Comment: *I had seen that other question* — I doubt that, as that question was created 5 days after this one was. ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at [`Connection::prepare`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.14.0/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html#method.prepare):

```
pub fn prepare<'a>(&'a self, sql: &str) -> Result<Statement<'a>>
```

If we ignore the `Result` (which just means that this function can fail), this means "return a `Statement` that can live no longer than the `Connection` that `prepare` was called on". This is likely due to the `Statement` containing a reference to the `Connection`.

However, if you have a reference to an item, then you can no longer move the item because the reference would be invalidated. Using that invalid reference would lead to memory unsafety, so it's prevented.

Basically, you need to mirror the lifetimes and ownership of these objects in your code, and so you cannot bundle the `Connection` and `Statement` in the same structure. Instead, one can reference the other.

Comment: Aha!  That's what I was missing.  Thank you.

Comment: What would a sql connection + 2 prepared statements look like in actual code exactly?

Comment: How would you implement "one can reference the other"?  Do I just need to have to variables with no connection in the code and pass both of them wherever I want the `Foo` from the original question?

Comment: @TroyDaniels two separate types, one not embedded in the other. You can usually pass just the one that contains the reference to the other, and access the referred-to item.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks.  In this case (rusqlite Connection and Statement), Statement has a reference to the Connection, but doesn't expose it.