# Compiler says that data cannot be shared between threads safely even though the data is wrapped within a Mutex

Tags: rust, thread-safety, mutex, rust-rocket

I'm using Rocket which has a `State` that it passes to the HTTP requests. This struct contains a `Mutex<DatastoreInstance>` which gives access to a SQLite database and is locked with a mutex to make read and writes safe.

```
pub struct DatastoreInstance {
    conn: Connection,
}
```

When the `DatastoreInstance` struct looked like this, with only a SQLite connection everything worked fine, but I then also wanted to add a transaction object within this struct:

```
pub struct DatastoreInstance {
    conn: Connection,
    events_transaction: Transaction,
}
```

This did not compile because the `Transaction` object needs to reference a `Connection` object which should have a lifetime which it is aware of.
The `Connection` and `Transaction` objects within rusqlite which I am using are defined as following:

```
pub struct Connection {
    db: RefCell<InnerConnection>,
    cache: StatementCache,
    path: Option<PathBuf>,
}

pub struct Transaction<'conn> {
    conn: &'conn Connection,
    drop_behavior: DropBehavior,
}
```

To solve the lifetime issues I had to add these lifetime parameters to get it working:

```
pub struct DatastoreInstance<'a> {
    conn: Connection,
    events_transaction: Transaction<'a>,
}
```

This was the result and was supposed to work according to my understanding of both lifetimes and mutexes, but I now get a compiler error telling me:

```
`std::cell::RefCell<lru_cache::LruCache<std::string::String, rusqlite::raw_statement::RawStatement>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |                                                                                                            
    = help: within `rusqlite::Connection`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::cell::RefCell<lru_cache::LruCache<std::string::String, rusqlite::raw_statement::RawStatement>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `rusqlite::cache::StatementCache`                        
    = note: required because it appears within the type `rusqlite::Connection`                                   
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&rusqlite::Connection`  
    = note: required because it appears within the type `datastore::DatastoreInstance<'_>`                       
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Mutex<datastore::DatastoreInstance<'_>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `endpoints::ServerState<'_>`                             
    = note: required by `rocket::State`
```

According to my understanding of mutexes, this code should be valid because the whole `DatastoreInstance` struct is wrapped within a `Mutex` which should guarantee that only one thread is referencing this object at a time.

What am I missing?

Why doesn't the compiler find `RefCell` to be safe anymore after being within a `Connection` referenced within a `Transaction` instead of solely within a `Connection`?

Do I have a bad understanding of how mutexes work? Are my lifetimes invalid and somehow break read/write safety? Is the design of having the `Connection` and `Transaction` within the same struct a bad design which breaks read/write safety? Do I need to redesign my data structures somehow to make this safe? Or am I just missing something very obvious?

Comment: You didn't include enough code to give any more help. For example, where is this `RefCell`, and where is the `Mutex` you mentioned? See [mcve].

Comment: Is the `Connection` type in your code referring to [this](http://jgallagher.github.io/rusqlite/src/rusqlite/lib.rs.html#180-184) ?

Comment: @PeterHall As I stated and is shown in the error message I am using a Mutex<DatastoreInstance> in my state. Prior to adding the Transaction to the struct the compiler didn't complain that RefCell within the Connection object couldn't be shared safely. The question is specifically why the compiler doesn't find RefCell to be safe anymore after being within a Connection referenced within a Transaction instead of solely within a Connection. I will start trying to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example but it's going to take some time.

Comment: @PeterHall Yes, that is the exact Connection object I am referencing, I should add more info about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Mutex` is only `Send` or `Sync` [if the value it contains is itself `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Send):

```
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Send for Mutex<T>    
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Sync for Mutex<T>
```

A `&T` is only `Send` [when `T` is `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html):

```
impl<'a, T> Send for &'a T
where
    T: Sync + ?Sized,
```

And a `RefCell` [is never `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#impl-Sync)

```
impl<T> !Sync for RefCell<T>
where
    T: ?Sized,
```

As the error message states, your transaction contains a reference to a `RefCell`. It doesn't matter that there's a mutex, it's inherently not memory-safe to share it across threads. A simple reproduction:

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, sync::Mutex};

struct Connection(RefCell<i32>);
struct Transaction<'a>(&'a Connection);

fn is_send<T: Send>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    let c = Connection(RefCell::new(42));
    let t = Transaction(&c);
    let m = Mutex::new(t);

    is_send(m);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `std::cell::RefCell<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     is_send(m);
   |     ^^^^^^^ `std::cell::RefCell<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Connection`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::cell::RefCell<i32>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Connection`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&Connection`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Transaction<'_>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Mutex<Transaction<'_>>`
note: required by `is_send`
  --> src/main.rs:6:1
   |
6  | fn is_send<T: Send>(_: T) {}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Why doesn't the compiler find `RefCell` to be safe anymore after being within a `Connection` referenced within a `Transaction` instead of solely within a `Connection`?

The `RefCell` is fine, it's the *reference* to a `RefCell` that is not.

> Is the design of having the `Connection` and `Transaction` within the same struct a bad design [...] Do I need to redesign my data structures

Yes.

- [How to store rusqlite Connection and Statement objects in the same struct in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32209391/155423)
- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: "A Mutex is only Send or Sync if the value it contains is itself Send" 
That makes a lot of sense, good point. I have tested your solution and it works, but I still have a hard time coming up with a good alternate design for my case (but that's actually a good thing since it forces me to design it safely and question my previous bad habit of using references within a mutex). I'm considering having a separate database thread which the  http servers worker threads send requests to.This would make sense since a SQLite database should preferably only be accessed from one thread at a time anyway.

Comment: @JohanBjäreholt that's getting closer to an "actor"-like model, which is a well-known and respected pattern. Seems very reasonable in this case. Channels to communicate between the threads should be a good fit, or you can investigate moving to a full-on actors framework like Actix.