# How can I pass a variable initialized in main to a Rocket route handler?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I have a variable that gets initialized in `main` (line 9) and I want to access a reference to this variable inside of one of my route handlers.

```
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> String {
    return fetch_data::fetch(format!("posts"), &redis_conn).unwrap(); // How can I get redis_conn?
}

fn main() {
    let redis_conn = fetch_data::get_redis_connection(); // initialized here

    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
}
```

In other languages, this problem would be solvable by using global variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please read the [Rocket documentation](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/), specifically the [section on state](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/state/#state).

Use [`State`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.4.2/rocket/struct.State.html) and [`Rocket::manage`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.4.2/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#method.manage) to have shared state:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket; // 0.4.2

use rocket::State;

struct RedisThing(i32);

#[get("/")]
fn index(redis: State<RedisThing>) -> String {
    redis.0.to_string()
}

fn main() {
    let redis = RedisThing(42);

    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(redis)
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .launch();
}
```

If you want to mutate the value inside the `State`, you will need to wrap it in a `Mutex` or other type of thread-safe interior mutability.

See also:

- [Compiler says that data cannot be shared between threads safely even though the data is wrapped within a Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52801244/155423)
- [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45674479/155423)
- [Share i32 mutably between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42849210/155423)

> this problem would be solvable by using global variables.

See also:

- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)